# Does data stored in threading.local get passed to child processes started with ProcessPoolExecutor?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

If I use `threading.local()` in my main process to store data, will it get copied to processes started using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`?

The documentation of [thread-local-data](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#thread-local-data) indicates that thread local data is not shared between threads. However, it does not mention if/how it is shared across threads in different processes.

Logically, I would think the answer to the question would be no. But I have not been able to find clear documentation on this use case.

Comment: That's not what I would think of as "working with" ProcessPoolExecutor. For it to "work with" ProcessPoolExecutor, I would expect different threads in a completely different process to *not* see data local to a thread in the original process.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That was my expectation as well. Turns out that it not the case.

Comment: I have made a few edits to hopefully clear up the thought process/question, I see how it could have been confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the data will be copied into the child processes if they are started with [fork](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) (which is the default on unix systems).

This seems non-intuitive but can be shown with a pretty simple example:

```python
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing
import threading

thread_data = threading.local()


def work():
    print("[{}] [{}] {}".format(
        multiprocessing.current_process().name,
        threading.current_thread().getName(),
        getattr(thread_data, 'my_data', None)
    ), flush=True)


def main():
    thread_data.my_data = 'Data from {}'.format(multiprocessing.current_process().name)

    work()

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []
        for i in range(8):
            futures.append(executor.submit(work))
        for _ in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            print("[{}] [{}] Work done.".format(
                multiprocessing.current_process().name,
                threading.current_thread().getName()
            ), flush=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

```
[MainProcess] [MainThread] Data from MainProcess
[ForkProcess-1] [MainThread] Data from MainProcess
[ForkProcess-2] [MainThread] Data from MainProcess
[ForkProcess-3] [MainThread] Data from MainProcess
[ForkProcess-4] [MainThread] Data from MainProcess
[MainProcess] [MainThread] Work done.
[ForkProcess-5] [MainThread] Data from MainProcess
[ForkProcess-6] [MainThread] Data from MainProcess
[MainProcess] [MainThread] Work done.
[ForkProcess-7] [MainThread] Data from MainProcess
[MainProcess] [MainThread] Work done.
[ForkProcess-8] [MainThread] Data from MainProcess
[MainProcess] [MainThread] Work done.
[MainProcess] [MainThread] Work done.
[MainProcess] [MainThread] Work done.
[MainProcess] [MainThread] Work done.
[MainProcess] [MainThread] Work done.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Notice that `thread_data.my_data` is set in the main thread of the main process. Once the process pool is started and work is submitted, the child process still has access to the thread local data from the parent process.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica because I have data that I want to be local to the thread/process that is accessing it without that data being shared across process/threads. The behavior shown here is, to me, counterintuitive and resulted in many hours of debugging for me. So I thought it was worth documenting and sharing.